# Some questions about Ward-Takahashi Identity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, yang-mills, gauge-symmetry, ward-identity

I'm a learner of Peskin and Schroeder's textbook of quantum field theory.

I have proceeded to [Ward-Takahashi identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward%E2%80%93Takahashi_identity) and have one question when I look for Wikipedia for reference.

The following is the Ward-Takahashi identity, where $M^{\mu}$ is the correlation function for $n$ inserting electrons and $n$ out-going electrons.
$$k_{\mu}M^{\mu}(k;p_1...p_n;q_1...q_n)=-e\sum_i[M_0(k;p_1...p_n;q_1...(q_i-k)...q_n)-M_0(k;p_1...(p_i+k)...p_n;q_1...q_n)].$$

The wiki says that

> *Note that if ($M^{\mu}$) has its external electrons on-shell, then the amplitudes on the right-hand side of this identity each have one external particle off-shell, and therefore they do not contribute to S-matrix elements.*

Does [*on-shell*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_shell_and_off_shell) means a divergent contribution according to LSZ reduction formula?

Besides, can you tell me why the S matrix is zero if all the external electrons in the left hand side are on shell?

Comment: You can refer to Peskin & Schroeder's book Chapter 5.2, page 142.

Answer (score 3):

With "on-shell" in QFT one usually refers to the mass-shell in momentum space defined by
$$ p_\mu p^\mu = m^2$$
Generally while performing calculations the momenta of the fields do not need to fulfill this relation. Still, any external particles that are identified with actual physical particles **have** to fulfill it. This is why the $M$ must have the external electrons on-shell in order to contribute to physical processes.

To the second question: $k^\mu$ is the four-momentum of a photon, i.e. it fulfills
$$k_\mu k^\mu = 0$$
If you subtract this from an electron's on-shell momentum it no longer fulfills the correct mass relation:
$$(p-k)_\mu (p-k)^\mu = p^2 + k^2 - 2 p \cdot k = m^2 + 0 + 2 p \cdot k \neq m^2$$
If the electrons were on-shell on the left hand side of your equation, they are not on-shell for any of the $M_0$ on the right-hand side and therefore the sum is zero.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Besides, when defining mass shell, $p^{\mu}p_{\mu}=m^2$, is m the bass mass or physical mass?

Comment: Well, if you define the mass-shell for physical particles, I'd say it's the pole mass. Generally though, afaik this is not defined and the value of $m^2$ may change depending on the renomalization scale.